# Wordpress with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

My system is: freebsd 10.3 apache24 php5.6 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.30
 WordPress 4.6.1 
My site on WP works perfectly, but when I install extension php56-mysqli-5.6.28 (for another project), it gives me error on main page:

> Invalid query: No database selected Whole query: SELECT count(*)    AS 'count' FROM `wp_posts` WHERE    `post_type` = 'dc_headfoot';

So when I disable mysqli in File /usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-mysqli.ini:

```
#extension=mysqli.so
```

My site works perfectly again. What am I doing wrong?
How do I fix this problem? I need mysqli and Wordpress at the same time.

Thank you!

Comment: Run `USE yourDBname;` before that query

Comment: Hello, sorry i am not SuperUser(super admin ;), you mean do it by ssh:
$ mysql -p
mysql > USE MyWordpressDBname;